# 404-page not found error Admin login page is not showing up?

Tags: django

when i give the URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000  it is showing successfully installed but when i give http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin it is showing 404 page not found. Cant reach to django administration login page

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin
Using the URLconf defined in myproject.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^admin/
The current path, admin, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: What about http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ (paying attention to last slash)?

Comment: do you have `'django.contrib.admin',` in your "installed apps" in settings.py? also you need `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),` in your root urls.py